# Not sure what the mistake is of if its an appscript limitation

Tags: google-apps-script

My code is supposed to loop and get a new row each time. It does everything correctly except that it keeps going to the first line. Its apparently looping correctly and the count is working in the while, but when I try to increment `nn`, it fails to do so, so instead of beginning after the cell it just left from, it just goes back to where it started. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
function doGet() { 
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('When Am I Eligible?');
//var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()/*.setHeight("400px;")*/.setWidth("800px");
//var submitButton = app.createButton('Check');


var key= ''
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET');
   var last=ss.getLastRow();
  var data=sh.getRange(1,1,last,5).getValues();
  var valB= Session.getEffectiveUser();
 var nn = 0;

   for (cnt=0; cnt<8; ++cnt){
  for(nn;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][1]==valB){
      var final = data[nn][0];
      var final1 = data[nn][1];
      var final2 = data[nn][2];
      var final3 = data[nn][3];
      var final4 = data[nn][4];


      break} ;// if a match in column B is found, break the loop
      }


 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()/*.setHeight("400px;")*/.setWidth("800px");
 var answer = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final)
 var answer1 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final1)
 var answer2 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final2)
 var answer3 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final3)
 var answer4 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final4)
 panel.add(answer).add(answer1).add(answer2).add(answer3).add(answer4);
 app.add(panel);

nn++



     if (cnt == 7) {
       break}
   }
  return app;
}
```

The problem appears to be that `data[nn]` and `nn` aren't the cell location. My log data shows this

- [13-06-14 09:04:58:671 EDT] 6.0 This is nn when it finds what its
  looking for
- [13-06-14 09:04:58:676 EDT] 7.0 this is me incrementing it.
- [13-06-14 09:04:58:676 EDT] 1.0 cnt
- [13-06-14 09:04:58:680 EDT] 25.0 then when it looks again and this is
  the nn value again.
- [13-06-14 09:04:58:680 EDT] 2.0

....etc

The weird part is, the value its finding is it the first cell & column. Its getting all these odd values, but its returning the value from the first column and row.

Answer (score 0):

Just at a glance, and this probably isn't your main problem, but you aren't declaring your **cnt** variable anywhere. try 
for (var cnt=0; cnt<8; ++cnt)

Comment: It isn't, the problem appears to be that `data[nn]` and `nn` aren't the cell location. My log data shows this

[13-06-14 09:04:58:671 EDT] 6.0 This is nn when it finds what its looking for
[13-06-14 09:04:58:676 EDT] 7.0 this is me incrementing it. 
[13-06-14 09:04:58:676 EDT] 1.0 cnt
[13-06-14 09:04:58:680 EDT] 25.0 then when it looks again and this is the nn value again. 
[13-06-14 09:04:58:680 EDT] 2.0
....etc

The weird part is, the value its finding is it the first cell & column. Its getting all these odd values, but its returning the value from the first column and row.

Answer (score 0):

Why should your code something not starting at the first line? You're initializing nn to zero at the beginning of your code. Your `nn++`statement is obsolete as all the variables aren't persistent.

You should try something like:

```
function doGet() { 
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
                .setTitle('When Am I Eligible?').setWidth("800px");
  app.add(app.createFlowPanel().setId('list'))
     .add(app.createHidden('firstRow', 0).setId('firstRow'))
     .add(app.createButton('Check')
       .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('buttonClick')
         .addCallbackElement(app.getElementById('list'))
         .addCallbackElement(app.getElementById('firstRow'))));
  return app;
}

function buttonClick(e) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key).getSheetByName('SHEET');
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
  var valB = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var list = app.getElementById('list').clear();
  var lines = 0;
  for (nn = Number(e.parameters.firstRow); nn < data.length; nn++) {
    if (data[nn][1]==valB){
      var = app.createHorizontalPanel();
      for (var i = 0; i < data[nn].length; i++)
        panel.add(app.createLabel(data[nn][i]));
      list.add(panel);
      if (++lines > 7) {
        nn++
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  app.getElementById('firstRow').setValue(nn);
  return app;
}
```

---> Remember that this is untested code I just typed into the browser window, don't complayn about typos :))